# How to get records month wise on rollover calender

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar, range

I am using following query to get records count on month wise and it is working fine:

```
SELECT MONTH(dte_cycle_count) MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM inventory
WHERE YEAR(dte_cycle_count)='2021' --OR (MONTH(dte_cycle_count) = '1' OR MONTH(dte_cycle_count) = '12')
GROUP BY MONTH(dte_cycle_count);
```

**Problem:**
Now I need to bind rollover calendar so user can scroll or click on next or previous button the next 12 Months record will be visible.
eg. Current month is MARCH, So default records will be from APR2020 to MARCH2021. If user click on previous then records will come MAR2020 to FEB2021.
How I can achieve this?
Please let me know if need more information. I will try my best to provide.

Comment: Your code will not return more than 12 rows.  However, you are specifying 14 months for the range.  I'm confused.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, description is updated.Hope it is correct now. Please check do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Changing year in the query will work fine right?

Comment: FYI, syntax like `WHERE YEAR(dte_cycle_count)='2021'` isn't good for perfomance; the query is not SARGable. Use proper date boundaries; for the above that would be `WHERE dte_cycle_count >= '20210101' AND dte_cycle_count < '20220101'`.

Comment: @GokulnathP because using this we are getting all months which have record and I am handling missing months with no record in code side. But I need it on month wise i.e 12 month count.

Comment: Pass in parameters with start and end dates maybe? What client language are you using?

Comment: @Larnu Sure, I will apply this one also. Thanks :-). Do you have any idea on my query?

Comment: Do you understand why `WHERE YEAR(dte_cycle_count)='2021'` does not do what you want? So - how should you change that? You need a proper lower boundary of February 1 2020, correct? While you can group by month (so long as you limit your query to 12 months), you probably should not in case you or someone else wants to use a longer time period. Typically one wants to see the year for each row in the resultset anyways - which is another argument against your grouping logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is a date list from which to join to your inventory table.

Like a numbers table, build a static table with columns for date, year, month, populated from whenever you need to far in the future.

You then select from this, applying your filtering range critera, and join to your inventory table.

For an efficient query, ideally your inventory table should have the relevant date portions eg year and month stored to match.

You don't want to be using functions on a datetime to extract the year or month as this is not sargable and will not allow any index to be used for a seek lookup.